# How to increase the media player volume step by step in android with background service

Tags: android

How to increase the media player sound from initial as step by step(low to high) using set-volume in android.

Answer (score 0):

This function is actualy wonderful. Thanks to it you can create a volume scale with any number of steps!

Let's assume you want 50 steps:

```
int maxVolume = 50;
```

Then to set setVolume to any value in this range (0-49) you do this:

```
float log1=(float)(Math.log(maxVolume-currVolume)/Math.log(maxVolume));
yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1-log1,log1);
```

Comment: In set volume there is two parameters.here it was One only